# How do I convert this data result structure into a swiftUI array?

Tags: swiftui

I'm using NotionSwift to access my Notion database.
It works great but i'm not sure how to phrase the results into an array

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yl2LT.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the results into a `@State` variable, then the View will automatically update whe the `@State` property changes

```
@State var resultList: [NotionSwift.page] = []
```

In your query function

```
self.resultList = data.results
```

Then the foreach to create a list

```
  ForEach(self.resultList , id: \.self) { index in 
  Text(self.resultList[index].id)
  }
```

I would recommend you to take a look at `@ObservableObject` and viewModels to make data retrieving tasks much easier

Comment: Thank you! when I try to access "data.results" I receive this error "Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'DatabaseQueryParams' that does not accept a closure"